# @JsonView doesn't work for me (Spring 4.1.5, Jackson 2.5.1)

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, json-view

I have a field in my Entity with @JsonView annotation:

```
@JsonView(View.Secure.class)
private String password;
```

Inside my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    @JsonView(View.Secure.class)
    public ResponseEntity<?> getAllUsers(){
        return createUserListResponse();
    }
```

My View class:

```
public class View {

    public static class Secure {}
}
```

I've expected that response will contain only "password" field, but instead it contains **nothing**. When i remove annotation `@JsonView(View.Secure.class)` from Controller - it works as usual and returns all fields. What am i doing wrong? Is it required to add some additional configuration into Spring config?

I used this tutorial: https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring

Comment: What if your method returns a List of Entity objects instead of the ResponseEntity?

Comment: Hi. I've figured out in what was a problem. 

This method: 
 `public ResponseEntity<?> getAllUsers(){
        return createUserListResponse();
    }`

calls another method which returns list of Entity objects and then create new ResponseEntity: `return new ResponseEntity<UserListVO>(users, HttpStatus.OK);`

I just annotate field in UserListVO class:

`public class UserListVO {
    @JsonView(View.Secure.class)
    private List<User> users;
}`

And it worked.